# Using YUI3 offline cache for html4 and html5

Tags: javascript, html, yui3, offline-caching, html4

I've been searching for an answer for my problem. I'm using YUI3 to develop a web application and I need to use the offline cache, the problem is; What will happen if someone access my YUI3 offline cache with old-type browser without html5 support? And if YUI3 offline cache will only support html5 supported browsers, what can I use to support offline caching for every browser?

Just to make it clear that I'll only use YUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YUI3 offline cache will automatically use YUI3 cache when the browser is not supporting HTML5 local storage.